# How To make Raspberry Pi Hardware PWM off after startup

Tags: gpio, boot, pwm, config.txt

I am driving motor using ESC with Hardware PWM signal comes from Raspberry Pi ,I set the **GPIO 19 (PIN 35)** to be **PWM1** , **the problem is when the Raspberry Pi startup it gives output value to PWM1 (GPIO 19)** which causing the motor to start spinning at slow speed ,
**How can stop that ? I want GPIO 19 to stop sending signal after the startup , unless I do it my self .**

NOTE : when the PWM was disabled in (/boot/config.txt) the GPIO 19 was Input ,so its wasn't sending any signal ,But after activating the PWM1 it changed to ALT5 and start giving signal just after startup.
[image]

Comment: Why not start hardware PWM with software after boot rather than using `/boot/config.txt` ?

Comment: what do you mean by start hardware PWM with software  ? all i need is to use Hardware PWM at GPIO 19 . therefore  I must enable it at /boot/config.txt , then reboot , to be ready to use . But the problem is that the PWM is starting automatically  just after boot .

Comment: You don't need to enable PWM in /boot/config.txt.

Comment: Yes , for hardware one you must enable PWM before you use it , check this : https://librpip.frasersdev.net/peripheral-config/pwm0and1/

Comment: That is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 4 libraries supporting hardware PWM; WiringPi (deprecated), pigpio (daemon), Pi.GPIO (python), pi-gpio (c).

All of these allow PWM to be started/stopped programatically at any time.

The kernel code started by dtoverlay uses the deprecated sysfs interface and is undocumented.